# How to extract specific information of summary output (e.g. last "n" lines of console output)?

Tags: r, summary

Using the `summary()` command for a survival model gives me a lot of output including the actual summary data that I care about at the end.

```
 4.59137577002053, 6.19301848049281, 6.99794661190965, 7.4113620807666, 
    0.0191649555099247, 7.86310746064339, 7.45790554414784, 6.31348391512663, 
    4.98288843258042, 5.67556468172485, 4.21081451060917, 3.06365503080082, 
    0.988364134154689, 2.42573579739904, 0.0328542094455852, 
    3.85763175906913, 4.02737850787132, 2.78165639972621, 0.00136892539356605, 
    0.722792607802875, 1.01848049281314, 7.32922655715264, 4.2984257357974
    )), row.names = c(NA, -180L), class = "data.frame"))

x observations deleted due to missingness 
 time n.risk n.event P((s0))   P(1)   P(2)
    1    17       4   0.962 0.0275 0.0110
    5    14       8   0.919 0.0520 0.0287
```

How do I save only the last *n* lines of the console output? I only want the last 3 lines which contains the risk information while the numerical values above are not needed.

Comment: Can you post reproducible example?

Comment: Try assigning the resturn value of `summary` and inspect it using `str`. If you are lucky, you can just extract what you need. If you are unlucky, a `print` method is involved. Then `capture.output` might be the best approach (and you might want to use `cat` when reproducing the console output).

Answer (score 2):

Using `tail` on `capture.output`

```
> n <- 3
> tail(capture.output(summary(lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars))), n)
[1] "Multiple R-squared:  0.6024,\tAdjusted R-squared:  0.5892 " "F-statistic: 45.46 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 1.788e-07"    
[3] ""
```

### However,

to get a "clean" version of the output, we need to understand how it's being created. (I'll stick to my `lm` example since you didn't provide one, but conceptually it's the same.)

Say, we're running `summary()` on a `lm` model.

```
> fit <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)
> sfit <- summary(fit)
```

When we `print` it, -- in this case we are dealing with an object of class `"summary.lm"` --

```
> class(sfit)
[1] "summary.lm"
```

the `stats:::print.summary.lm` method is dispatched accordingly.

```
> sfit
> print(sfit)  ## same
> stats:::print.summary.lm(sfit)  ## same
> stats:::print.summary.lm(unclass(summary(fit)))  ## same
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.7121 -2.1122 -0.8854  1.5819  8.2360 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 30.09886    1.63392  18.421  < 2e-16 ***
hp          -0.06823    0.01012  -6.742 1.79e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.863 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6024,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5892 
F-statistic: 45.46 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 1.788e-07
```

To see which method is dispatched, we can do e.g.

```
> sloop::s3_dispatch(print(sfit))
=> print.summary.lm
 * print.default
```

While the output is just formatted text, the `"summary.lm"` object contains the information we want. It is actually of type `"list"`,

```
> typeof(sfit)
[1] "list"
```

and we can examine it using `str()`.

```
> str(sfit)
List of 11
 $ call         : language lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
 $ terms        :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language mpg ~ hp
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(mpg, hp)
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "mpg" "hp"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "hp"
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "hp"
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(mpg, hp)
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "numeric" "numeric"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "mpg" "hp"
 $ residuals    : Named num [1:32] -1.594 -1.594 -0.954 -1.194 0.541 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
 $ coefficients : num [1:2, 1:4] 30.0989 -0.0682 1.6339 0.0101 18.4212 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "hp"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "t value" "Pr(>|t|)"
 [...]
```

We can also `unclass` it, to see it as `list`

```
> print(unclass(sfit))  ## not generally recommended to do, as it might be huge!
```

If we now want, say, the `coefficients` of this `"summary.lm"` object, we can now see that we can simply subset the underlying list.

```
> sfit$coefficients
               Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 30.09886054  1.6339210 18.421246 6.642736e-18
hp          -0.06822828  0.0101193 -6.742389 1.787835e-07
```

If the desired part is not contained in the list (e.g. the residual quantiles), we can examine the method -- here `stats:::print.summary.lm` -- to see how these are created.

*Note,* that this answer deals with an S3 object,

```
> isS4(sfit)
[1] FALSE
```

In principle, the logic for S4 is the same, but you might have to deal with different syntax such as operators `sfit@coefficients` and functions, e.g. `slotNames()`.

Comment: This is working but the formatting is a bit messed up.

Comment: @Mark I think you have a misconception of how console output is created.

Comment: can you elaborate?